# Where is the MySql 5.6 equivalent of `MySQLInstanceConfig.exe` to edit configuration files?

Tags: mysql, instance

I installed MYSQL 5.6, This works fine.

On another server I have MYSQL 5.1
The 5.1 version includes `MySQLInstanceConfig.exe` in the `bin` folder

But version 5.6 does not include this file.

So my question is, how can I configure the instance on MySql version 5.6?

Answer (score 6):

It has been replaced by [MySQL Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-installer.html), which is available as both a [GUI](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-installer-gui.html) and [console](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/MySQLInstallerConsole.html) application.

Comment: you know if is necessary backup all database first run this process.?

Comment: Can I ask: do you find this deployment strategy sound and good? It seems somewhat exotic for me as a deployment guy, but it is not the worst I have seen by any stretch.