# MySQL installer for Windows (MSI) for 5.7.33 insists on installing 8.0 components

Tags: mysql, windows-installer

Our application database schema is compatible with MySQL 5.7.  A new team member accidentally installed MySQL 8.0.22 on Windows 10 using the MSI installer.  The uninstall of version 8.0.22 was successful.  However, the subsequent install of version 5.7.32 insists on re-installing version 8.0.22 components.  How can version 8.0.22 be cleanly uninstalled to enable a correct 5.7.32 install?

[image: MySQL 5.7.32 MSI installer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it looks like MySQL implemented an MSI installer that can lay down bits from multiple releases. In the Setup Type phase, you can choose which release to install. As such, withdrawing this question accordingly.

Comment: I remember looking at this at one point, and it was quite confusing. [I wrote something up here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51293749/how-to-install-mysql-unattended-with-custom-settings).